# Transport own class with Intent between objects

Tags: android

HI,

i'm programming an android application using the StartActivityForResult() - Method.
But, i want to get as result an own class, not a string or something like that.
how can i tell the intent to use the class i wrote to give back?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have your class implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html). Also, this technique is only recommended for activities within the same application.